# Get clicked element's locator information

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation

I'm trying to design an UI utility to identify an element's locator information (like `id`, `name`, `class`, `xpath`, etc..) I will use these locator information to automate test scripts.

I'm not an expert in `JavaScript`, but I'm looking for a solution in pure `JavaScript`, so that I do not have dependency on any third party library (like `jQuery` and others).

I've been trying this so far with little success.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    var text = target.textContent;
    console.log(text);
    var id = target.getAttribute('id');
    console.log(id);
    var name = target.getAttribute('name');
    console.log(name);
    var Class = target.getAttribute('class');
    console.log(Class);
}, false);
```

Please also suggest if there is any existing tool which can do it for me, so that I don't end up re-inventing the wheel.

**Here is what I exactly want out of it:**

1. Highlight the element hovered/clicked within DOM
2. Populate locator information for any clicked/hovered element in DOM
3. Make the page un-interactive while the utility is being used. (stop it from navigating when a link is being clicked)

Comment: for #3 I don't think you can target the body... event will bubble-up to body from the item clicked.  Not sure about the event at that point, but it seems like that part should work.  Are you not getting any info output to the console?

Comment: Yes, the code that I have right now print the values to console. But the problem is, as soon as a navigation takes place, all the details in console is being wiped off.